# XE2 project creates FastReport DCUs

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, fastreport

I'm currently working on a delphi project, my problem is that everytime I compile the project a couple of FastReport DCUs are created, but I'm not using `FastReport` at all.

I'm not using a single `FastReport` component.

The DCUs are called `'fs_iclassesrtti'`, `'fs_idialogsrtti`', `'fs_iformsrtti'`, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, they're used by some other unit you're using.

One way to find out which is to a) find the .Pas versions of these files, b) temporarily move them (don't delete them!) so that they're not on Delphi's search path then c) do a Build on your project; the Build should fail and the IDE should open the (first) source file which uses one of them. Repeat d) until all are found